# フォームアプリケーションからコンソールへ出力

Tags: windows, c++-cli, コマンドプロンプト

開発環境: Visual Studio 2012

フォームアプリケーションとして作成したプロジェクトに対して、
`System::Console::WriteLine("XXXX");`をコマンドプロンプトに出力する為には、
プロジェクトのプロパティのどの設定箇所を変更すれば良いのでしょうか？

コマンドプロンプト上でYYY.exeを叩いて実行して、
コマンドプロンプト上に標準出力する為のプロパティ設定を教えて下さい。

なお、はじめからコンソールアプリケーションで作る、というのはＮＧです。
フォームアプリケーションとして作成する理由があるのです。
フォームアプリケーションをあたかもコンソールアプリケーションのように標準出力を変更する設定箇所がどこかにあるはずですが、見つけられません。
※以前、同じことをした事があるので、出来るはずです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10284/

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/80798

Answer (score 2):

> コマンドプロンプト上でYYY.exeを叩いて実行して、
>   コマンドプロンプト上に標準出力する為のプロパティ設定を教えて下さい。

[AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx) を呼び出すことで実現できます。もちろんコマンドプロンプト以外から起動された場合は表示する先が存在しないため何も表示されません。

なお、呼び出し元のコマンドプロンプトはフォームアプリケーションのプロセスを起動した後、プロンプトを表示して次のコマンドを受け付けているため、意図しない動作になるような気がします。

> 質問は System::Console::WriteLine("XXXX"); を有効にするためのプロパティページの設定箇所はどこか？です。

[Linker - System にあるSubsystemの項目](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem)を **Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)** から
 **Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)** に変更することで実現できますが、この設定こそがフォームアプリケーションとコンソールアプリケーションの違いを決定付ける設定ですので、ここを変更することは「はじめからコンソールアプリケーションで作る」になってしまうため、回答から除外しました。

Comment: 質問は
System::Console::WriteLine("XXXX");
を有効にするためのプロパティページの設定箇所はどこか？です。

Comment: ご教授お願いしますお願いします

Comment: @oneeeeggg さん更新しました。質問者さんは何を求めているのでしょうか？

Comment: プロパティページの設定箇所はどこか、です。

Comment: ＸＸＸのＸＸＸをクリックしたＸＸＸＸを編集する、といった回答をお願いします、

Comment: @oneeeeggg さん、質問文に具体的な環境が明示されていない以上、操作方法を提示できないのは自明で、その場合はリンク先の公式ドキュメントをご自身で理解する必要があります。それよりもフォームアプリケーションとコンソールアプリケーションとを決定付ける設定を変更する必要がありそうなので「コンソールアプリケーションがNGである理由」を明示してください。理由によっては「実現できない」という回答にもなり得ますし。

Comment: 「Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) に変更する」手順をご教授下さい。

Comment: 環境はＶＳ２０１２です。プロパティページを２時間くらいかけて全てみたのですが設定箇所を発見できませんでした。どこでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/fcc1zstk(v=vs.110).aspx
にてVS2012の設定手順を参照することはできます。

> Visual Studio 開発環境でこのリンカー オプションを設定するには

@sayuriさん
が書かれているように、これが本来行いたいことかはこちらには分かりません。